# Identifying lattices

Tags: lattice-orders

A lattice $H$ is a partial order such that each pair of elements $a$ and $b$ has

- a least upper bound $u \in H : a \leq u \land b \leq u$ and
- a greatest lower bound $l \in H : l \leq a \land l \leq b$

Transitivity is implied in the following definitions, e.g. $\{ (A, B), (B, C) \}$ implies $(A, C)$.

$H_1 = \{ (A, B), (B, C), (C, D) \}$ is a lattice as the above conditions hold true for all pairs $\{ A, B, C, D \} \times \{ A, B, C, D \}$:

```
A → B → C → D
```

$H_2 = \{ (A, B), (A, C), (A, D), (B, E), (C, F), (D, E), (D, F) \}$ is not a lattice as there is no least upper bound for $E, F$:

```
E   F
|\ /|
B D C
 \|/
  A
```

What about $H_3 = \{ (A, B), (A, C), (B, D), (B, E), (C, D), (C, E), (D, F), (E, F) \}$?

```
  F
 / \
D   E
| X |
B   C
 \ /
  A
```

Is this a lattice? Is $A$ the infimum of $(D, E)$ and $F$ the supremum of $(B, C)$?

Comment: Hint: Look at $D$ and $E$. You have $C\le D\ \wedge C\le E$, but you also have $B\le D\ \wedge B\le E$, and also $A\le D\ \wedge A\le E\ $. So, $\{A, B, C\}$ are the lower bounds for $D$ and $E$. But, what is the greatest of them all?

Comment: @Poypoyan What I don't understand is whether the pure existence of any lower bound implies the existence a greatest lower bound. If it does, then it is a lattice, but reading your comment I assume it does not.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ea/Hasse_diagram_of_powerset_of_3.svg) is a lattice. But doesn't your argument apply to $\{x,y\}$ as well?

Comment: In my comment, $\{A,B,C\}$ are lower bounds, but which (one) element in $\{A,B,C\}$ is "greater" than the others? If you say, for example, that $B$ is the greatest, then is $B\ge A$ _and_ $B\ge C$? No. You will deduce that none of $\{A,B,C\}$ is the g.l.b, or in other words, $D$ and $E$ doesn't have a g.l.b.

Comment: So, you can have lower bounds of a pair, but it does not imply that you automatically have the _greatest_ lower bound. The same applies to the lowest upper bound.

Comment: @Poypoyan Thank you for your response! In [this graph](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ea/Hasse_diagram_of_powerset_of_3.svg) found on Wikipedia, $\{x,y\}$ has lower bounds $\{ \{x\}, \{y\}, \varnothing \}$, so again there would be no greatest lower bound, yet Wikipedia says it is a lattice. What am I missing? (Can be found in picture 1 [of this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)#Examples).)

Comment: $\{x,y\}$ is a lower bound of itself because $\{x,y\}\ge \{x,y\}$.

Comment: @Poypoyan You are right, thanks so much! I really could not wrap my head around that!

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on the comment: $D\wedge E$ does not currently exist, but if you added restrictions like $D\leq E\leq B\leq C$ then you would have a lattice.